# how to find out weekly users growth rate on my website with node.js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
router.get("/users-growth-weekly", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let previousWeekStart = new Date();
    previousWeekStart.setDate(previousWeekStart.getDate() - 13);
    previousWeekStart.setHours(0);
    previousWeekStart.setMinutes(0);
    previousWeekStart.setSeconds(0);

    let previousWeekEnd = new Date();
    previousWeekEnd.setDate(previousWeekEnd.getDate() - 7);
    previousWeekEnd.setHours(23);
    previousWeekEnd.setMinutes(59);
    previousWeekEnd.setSeconds(59);

    let presentWeekStart = new Date();
    presentWeekStart.setDate(presentWeekStart.getDate() - 6);
    presentWeekStart.setHours(0);
    presentWeekStart.setMinutes(0);
    presentWeekStart.setSeconds(0);

    let presentWeekEnd = new Date();
    presentWeekEnd.setHours(23);
    presentWeekEnd.setMinutes(59);
    presentWeekEnd.setSeconds(59);

    const previousWeekUsers = await Account.find({ createdAt: { $gte: previousWeekStart, $lt: previousWeekEnd } }).countDocuments();
    const presentWeekUsers = await Account.find({ createdAt: { $gte: presentWeekStart, $lt: presentWeekEnd } }).countDocuments();

    if (previousWeekUsers === 0) {
      const growthRate = presentWeekUsers * 100;
      return res.status(200).json({ growthRate })
    } else {
      const growthRate = (((presentWeekUsers / previousWeekUsers) - 1) * 100).toFixed(2);
      return res.status(200).json({ growthRate })
    };
  }
  catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({ err })
  }
});
```

I have applied this query and formula, but I think it's wrong, can any please help how to find out weekly users growth rate on my website with node.js and MongoDB